# Can I use $PC in MIPS

Tags: mips

As far as I know, program counter, $PC is hidden from users. It isn't one of the 32 registers.

I want to do the following, instead of using jal

```
$ra <= PC + 4
j my_function
# instead of jal my_function
```

Is is possible to do this? I know JAIL is a macro.

How can I jump to a function without using JAL and able to return to the next instruction of the caller? Thanks.

Thanks!

---

> One supported method of "discovering" the PC in code is to use JAL
>   with a zero offset (to jump/link to the next instruction), then read
>   the PC out of R31.

Attempt:

```
..statements before jump...
jal $0
addi $t3, $ra, 4
..statements when function returns..
```

I end up in infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a JAL to find out the PC is quite useless since you can use that JAL to do the jump... One way to do it is using LA pseudo-instruction, something like:

```
la $ra, current
addiu $ra, $ra, 8
current:
j example
nop
return:
j return
nop

example:
jr $ra
nop
```

Comment: Thanks! I will need a little more time to check this. Thanks.  :)))